# Windows Media Player album-art files re-appear after been deleted from folder

Tags: windows-media-player, album-art

I'm trying to get rid of files `AlbumArtSmall.jpg` and `Folder.jpg` to add the right ones on Windows Media Player (WMP). So far I have been able to un-hide these files and delete them. Right after I add this folder to a WMP library, the deleted files re-appear.

I'd like to know:

1. Why this is happening and,
2. How to make sure these deleted files never re-appear again.

My goal is to delete bad album art pictures to later apply the right ones.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to manually delete those files if you just want to replace these with the correct album art. The correct way to do this is to first copy the new album art (for example, from your browser). Then navigate to the album in WMP's library, right-click the current album art picture and select `Paste album art`.

This will replace the album art in the library as well as create new album art image files in the album's directory.

Comment: Right, already tried that, when there is no art image in the music file, 'Paste album art' works fine, but if there is an existing art image, WMP wouldn't replace the old art picture with the new pasted one. I read in another post that WMP sometimes can't overwrite album art pictures, I witnessed that first hand. That's why I tried to first delete them manually and then paste the right picture using WMP.

Comment: Could you update your original post with some more details: your version of WMP/Windows and the file type of the affected music files? Thanks!

Comment: Also, I suggest that you check in File Explorer whether the music files aren't accidentally marked as read-only. Same for the hidden album art JPG files.